# Isapi rewriter seems to be inserting an extra "index.php" 

Tags: codeigniter, isapi-rewrite

I am trying to  do something simple on Windows Server: I want to make the URL `www.xxxxx.co.uk/index.php/xxxxxx/xxxxx` appear as `www.xxxxx.co.uk/xxxxxx/xxxxx` on a site that was built using [Code Igniter](http://codeigniter.com/).

My web host has set up the version 3 of Isapi Rewriter.

My `.htaccess` file says:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .? index.php/%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

but now, no images are being loaded.

On closer inspection, it appears that an extra `index.php` is being loaded after the domain name.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to see the CodeIgniter `config/config.php` file.

On line 29, make sure the `$config['index_page']` variable is set to blank.